# Wi-Fi adapter install error Linux Mint

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, linux-mint, wifi-configuration

All right?

I have an adapter that has worked on Windows 10. But on Cinnamon, it is not even recognized.

Follows some results, being the first one the attempt to install the driver that came with the adapter in a CD:

```
$ sudo bash install.sh
##################################################
Realtek Wi-Fi driver Auto installation script
Novembor, 21 2011 v1.1.0
##################################################
Decompress the driver source tar ball:
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222.tar.gz
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/runwpa
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_xmit.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_ioctl_query.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_bt_mp.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/efuse/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_recv.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_br_ext.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_wapi.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_eeprom.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_debug.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_tdls.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_p2p.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_ieee80211.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_security.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_cmd.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_mlme.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_mp.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_wapi_sms4.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_sreset.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_sta_mgt.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_rf.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_pwrctrl.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_wlan_util.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_mlme_ext.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_io.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_ap.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_led.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_ioctl_rtl.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_mp_ioctl.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_ioctl_set.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_iol.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/wlan0dhcp
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/osdep_service.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/ioctl_linux.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/recv_linux.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/pci_ops_linux.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/custom_gpio_linux.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/mlme_linux.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/gspi_intf.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/pci_intf.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/sdio_intf.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/xmit_linux.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/gspi_ops_linux.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/usb_ops_linux.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/sdio_ops_linux.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/hal_com.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/wlan_bssdef.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/cmd_osdep.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_recv.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_mlme_ext.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/wifi.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192c_led.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192d_recv.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/custom_gpio.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/HalPwrSeqCmd.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8723a_dm.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8188e_dm.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/Hal8192CPhyReg.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/gspi_ops_linux.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8723a_pg.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/Hal8192DPhyCfg.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192d_hal.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192c_dm.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192c_rf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_android.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/drv_types_gspi.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192c_recv.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8188e_recv.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/nic_spec.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/usb_osintf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192d_dm.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8723a_recv.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_xmit.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192c_event.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/Hal8188EPhyReg.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_qos.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_pwrctrl.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192c_xmit.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192d_spec.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/gspi_hal.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/osdep_ce_service.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/sdio_ops.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8723a_sreset.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8723a_rf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/ieee80211.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/recv_osdep.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/drv_types_linux.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_efuse.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/gspi_ops.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/sdio_ops_ce.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/usb_ops.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8188e_xmit.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_ht.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/HalVerDef.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/ioctl_cfg80211.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/ethernet.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/Hal8188EPhyCfg.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/mp_custom_oid.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_ioctl_rtl.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/sdio_ops_linux.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/Hal8723APhyCfg.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192c_spec.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_mlme.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8723a_hal.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/drv_types.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_sreset.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/ieee80211_ext.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/drv_types_ce.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/Hal8192CPhyCfg.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/Hal8723APhyReg.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8188e_cmd.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8188e_rf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192d_led.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/byteorder/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/byteorder/swab.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/byteorder/swabb.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/byteorder/big_endian.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/byteorder/little_endian.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/byteorder/generic.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_mp_ioctl.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/sdio_ops_xp.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/usb_ops_linux.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8723a_xmit.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/sdio_osintf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/Hal8723PwrSeq.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8188e_sreset.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_p2p.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/pci_hal.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/drv_conf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/usb_vendor_req.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/linux/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/linux/wireless.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/osdep_service.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8188e_hal.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8188e_led.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/gspi_osintf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_ioctl_query.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_eeprom.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/drv_types_xp.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8723a_cmd.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_byteorder.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192d_xmit.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_version.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8723a_spec.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192d_cmd.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_ioctl_set.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/h2clbk.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/pci_osintf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_bt_mp.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_cmd.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192d_rf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/pci_ops.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_tdls.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192c_cmd.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_event.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/mlme_osdep.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_debug.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_ap.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/osdep_intf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_wapi.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/hal_intf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/sta_info.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8188e_spec.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_iol.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_mp_phy_regdef.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_rf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/Hal8188EPwrSeq.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/usb_hal.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/autoconf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_security.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/sdio_hal.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_io.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/Hal8192DPhyReg.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_br_ext.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/circ_buf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/basic_types.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192c_hal.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/ip.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_led.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/if_ether.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/xmit_osdep.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192c_sreset.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8723a_bt-coexist.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_mp.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_ioctl.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/drv_types_sdio.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8723a_led.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/ifcfg-wlan0
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/Makefile
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/Kconfig
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_types.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/HalPhyRf.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/HalPhyRf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_RegDefine11N.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_precomp.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/Hal8188EReg.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalHWImg8188E_BB.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/odm_RTL8188E.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/Hal8188ERateAdaptive.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalHWImg8188E_RF.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalHWImg8188E_RF.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalHWImg8188E_FW.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalPhyRf_8188e.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/odm_RegConfig8188E.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/odm_RTL8188E.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalHWImg8188E_MAC.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/Hal8188EFWImg_CE.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalHWImg8188E_MAC.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalHWImg8188E_BB.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/Hal8188EFWImg_CE.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalHWImg8188E_FW.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/odm_RegConfig8188E.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/Hal8188ERateAdaptive.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalPhyRf_8188e.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_HWConfig.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_debug.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_interface.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_interface.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_HWConfig.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_reg.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_RegDefine11AC.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_debug.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/hal_intf.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_sreset.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_rxdesc.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_cmd.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_rf6052.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/Hal8188EPwrSeq.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_mp.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_phycfg.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_dm.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/usb/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/usb/usb_halinit.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/usb/rtl8188eu_led.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/usb/rtl8188eu_recv.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/usb/rtl8188eu_xmit.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/usb/usb_ops_linux.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_hal_init.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_xmit.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/hal_com.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/HalPwrSeqCmd.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/clean
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222
Authentication requested [root] for make clean:
rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
rm -fr .tmp_versions
rm -fr Module.symvers ; rm -fr Module.markers ; rm -fr modules.order
cd core/efuse ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd hal/rtl8188e/usb ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd hal/rtl8188e ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd hal/OUTSRC/ ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep/linux ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/build M=/home/^/Documents/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic'
Makefile:976: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
CC [M] /home/^/Documents/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/^/Documents/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_cmd.c:23:0:
/home/^/Documents/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘_init_timer’:
/home/^/Documents/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/osdep_service.h:956:8: error: ‘_timer {aka struct timer_list}’ has no member named ‘data’
ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
^~
/home/^/Documents/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/osdep_service.h:957:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
init_timer(ptimer);
^~~~~~~~~~
_init_timer
In file included from /home/^/Documents/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_cmd.c:23:0:
/home/^/Documents/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘thread_enter’:
/home/^/Documents/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/osdep_service.h:1423:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘daemonize’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
daemonize("%s", name);
^~~~~~~~~
/home/^/Documents/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/osdep_service.h:1424:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘allow_signal’; did you mean ‘do_signal’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
allow_signal(SIGTERM);
^~~~~~~~~~~~
do_signal
/home/^/Documents/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘flush_signals_thread’:
/home/^/Documents/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/osdep_service.h:1437:6: error: implicit declaration of function ‘signal_pending’; did you mean ‘timer_pending’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
if (signal_pending (current))
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
timer_pending
/home/^/Documents/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/osdep_service.h:1439:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘flush_signals’; did you mean ‘do_signal’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
flush_signals(current);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~
do_signal
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/home/^/Documents/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/^/Documents/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/home/^/Documents/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/^/Documents/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic'
Makefile:678: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04e8:61b6 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd M3 Portable Hard Drive 1TB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 18f8:0f97
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2a7a:9a18
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 02)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [1043:8347]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
```

rfkill list: `no results at all`

mokutil --sb-state;

```
EFI variables are not supported on this system
```

iwconfig:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.
```

ifconfig:

```
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.32  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::36e9:aa16:1c30:69a7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ^^^^^^^^^  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 165145  bytes 139091905 (139.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 143583  bytes 24463616 (24.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 19406  bytes 1752358 (1.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 19406  bytes 1752358 (1.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

nmcli d:

```
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION         
enp2s0  ethernet  connected  Wired connection 1 
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

Thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the guys from the [Mint Forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=287314&p=1590845#p1590190), helped superbly along with the guys from [VivaoLinux.com.br](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/topico/Rede-Wireless/Configuracao-da-Realtek-Semiconductor-Co-Ltd-RTL810126E-PCI-Express-FastGigabit-Erro-varios):

I prefer to live a response as this may help someone in the future! :D

So, the steps are:

```
git clone https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu.git
cd rtl8188fu
make 
sudo make install
```

Then, if there's the following problem:

```
$ make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/build M=/home/^/rtl8188fu  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic'
Makefile:976: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_security.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_debug.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_io.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_ioctl_query.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_ioctl_set.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_ieee80211.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_mlme.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_mlme_ext.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_wlan_util.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_vht.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_pwrctrl.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_rf.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_recv.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_sta_mgt.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_ap.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_p2p.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_tdls.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_br_ext.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_iol.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_sreset.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_btcoex.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_beamforming.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_odm.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/os_dep/osdep_service.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/os_dep/linux/usb_ops_linux.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/os_dep/linux/ioctl_linux.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/os_dep/linux/xmit_linux.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/os_dep/linux/mlme_linux.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/os_dep/linux/recv_linux.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/os_dep/linux/wifi_regd.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/os_dep/linux/rtw_proc.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/os_dep/linux/ioctl_mp.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/hal_intf.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/hal_com.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/hal_com_phycfg.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/hal_phy.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/hal_dm.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/hal_btcoex.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/hal_mp.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/hal_hci/hal_usb.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/led/hal_usb_led.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/HalPwrSeqCmd.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/rtl8188f/Hal8188FPwrSeq.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/rtl8188f/rtl8188f_sreset.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/rtl8188f/rtl8188f_hal_init.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/rtl8188f/rtl8188f_phycfg.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/rtl8188f/rtl8188f_rf6052.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/rtl8188f/rtl8188f_dm.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/rtl8188f/rtl8188f_rxdesc.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/rtl8188f/rtl8188f_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/rtl8188f/usb/usb_halinit.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/rtl8188f/usb/rtl8188fu_led.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/rtl8188f/usb/rtl8188fu_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/rtl8188f/usb/rtl8188fu_recv.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/rtl8188f/usb/usb_ops.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/efuse/rtl8188f/HalEfuseMask8188F_USB.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/phydm_debug.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/phydm_antdiv.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/phydm_antdect.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/phydm_interface.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/phydm_hwconfig.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/phydm.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/halphyrf_ce.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/phydm_edcaturbocheck.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/phydm_dig.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/phydm_pathdiv.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/phydm_rainfo.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/phydm_dynamicbbpowersaving.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/phydm_powertracking_ce.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/phydm_dynamictxpower.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/phydm_adaptivity.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/phydm_cfotracking.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/phydm_noisemonitor.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/phydm_acs.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/phydm_beamforming.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/txbf/halcomtxbf.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/txbf/haltxbfinterface.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/rtl8188f/halhwimg8188f_bb.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/rtl8188f/halhwimg8188f_mac.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/rtl8188f/halhwimg8188f_rf.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/rtl8188f/halhwimg8188f_fw.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/rtl8188f/phydm_regconfig8188f.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/rtl8188f/halphyrf_8188f.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/hal/phydm/rtl8188f/phydm_rtl8188f.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_mp.o
  CC [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/core/rtw_mp_ioctl.o
  LD [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/rtl8188fu.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /home/^/rtl8188fu/rtl8188fu.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/^/rtl8188fu/rtl8188fu.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic'
```

That will probably generate the following:

```
$ sudo make install
install -p -m 644 .ko  /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
install: cannot stat '.ko': No such file or directory
Makefile:481: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Do:

```
sudo apt install libelf-dev
```

Then:

```
cd rtl8188fu
make clean
cd
sudo dkms add ./rtl8188fu
sudo dkms install rtl8188fu/1.0
```

Now, reboot. Your Wi-Fi should now be working!

Thanks a lot and all the best!

Comment: Excelenteeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone reach here finding solution to install driver simply follow "How to install" steps from following repository.

https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu